# Change a managed path from explicit to wildcard inclusion

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, powershell-2.0

Can a managed path within a web application be changed from explicit to wildcard via a powershell script?  I could move the sites to another pathway and back, but was looking for a quicker way.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be helpful.

[Define managed paths for a web application by using Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845.aspx#section2)